# Get complete class name given prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm using a css class to define grouping in table rows:

```
<table>
    <tr class="otherClasses group1">...</tr>
    <tr class="otherClasses group1">...</tr>
    <tr class="otherClasses group2">...</tr>
    <tr class="otherClasses group2">...</tr>
    ...
    <tr class="otherClasses groupN">...</tr>
</table>
```

Now I need to loop through all the rows in my table and get `groupX` for each one. Then I'll split the string and extract group ID.
What's the correct/best way to get `groupX` class among all `tr` classes only giving `group` prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will return an array with "group" classes:

```
var groupClasses = $(".otherClasses").map(function() {
    return (this.className.match(/group\d+/) || []).pop();
}).get();
```

Or in `each()` iteration:

```
$(".otherClasses").each(function() {
    var groupClass = (this.className.match(/group\d+/) || []).pop();
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `attribute contains` selector in jQuery:

```
$('tr[class*="group"]')
```

Have a look at [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) documentation for more info.  You may need to tweak the value depending on your specifics (e.g. add a space before *group*).